# AFwall+ sometimes can't apply rules and doesn't get root

Tags: root-access, firewall

Sometimes [AFwall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall&hl=en_US&gl=US)+ has an error. It says it can't apply the iptable rules and that it failed to get root. I look in Magisk and there is no entry for it. Rebooting the phone fixes the problem. I'm just wondering if there's a more permanent solution?

Comment: Which Android device and Android version are you using? Which Magisk version are you using?

Comment: @Firelord Galaxy S20 with its stock Android 11. Magisk 23. Used to have Xposed but removed it.